# how I change other App likn to open link in browser android app

Tags: android

in my app there a button open other app in google play 
but i want to change it to open a likn taht open my web site

Code:

```
this.followImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {
          OtherApp.openIntentOrInMarket(HomeActivity.this, "mobi.infinityApp.SnapPhoto", "mobi.infinityApp.SnapPhoto.activity.LoadingActivity");
          HomeActivity.this.homeClickLog.put("click", "SnapPhoto");
          Answers.getInstance().logCustom((CustomEvent)new CustomEvent("home").putCustomAttribute("click", "SnapPhoto"));
        }
      });
```

Comment: [Please format code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a button clickable to open up a certain link, try the following:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Uri uri = Uri.parse("INSERT URL HERE WITH THE APP PROTOCOL");
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```